# Why Android geRestrictBackgroundStatus always return same value, whatever setting I made to app?

Tags: kotlin, android-settings, flutter-android

It is my first experience writing native android call from flutter, (0 kotlin experience) ). I have generated flutter plugin source and put there simple code to call androids https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getRestrictBackgroundStatus(). It must return application background restriction status. For example:

[image]

This value should correspond (not 100% sure) to RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_ENABLED return value of api function. But whatever settings I have made in phone the function returns RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_DISABLED. Here is my plugin code:

```kotlin
package com.kidcontrol.androidpwutil

import android.content.Context
import androidx.annotation.NonNull

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi

/** AndroidpwutilPlugin */
class AndroidpwutilPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  /// The MethodChannel that will the communication between Flutter and native Android
  ///
  /// This local reference serves to register the plugin with the Flutter Engine and unregister it
  /// when the Flutter Engine is detached from the Activity
  private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel
  private val METHOD_GET_RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS = "getRestrictBackgroundStatus"
  private lateinit var context: Context

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "androidpwutil")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    context = flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext
  }

  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "getPlatformVersion") {
      result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
    } else if (call.method == METHOD_GET_RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS) {
      var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
      if (connectivityManager != null) {
        result.success(connectivityManager.restrictBackgroundStatus);
      } else {
        val error = ClassNotFoundException()
        result.error(error.message, error.localizedMessage, error)
      }
    } else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
  }
}
```

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong, to be able to get correct value of the app setting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with android settings and discovered that It was missing idea this relation between getRestrictBackgroundStatus call and the android system setting shown in the picture in my question. It does correspond to the value of "Data Saver" setting:

[image]